# Mingw compiler doesn't detect the opencv libraries even though it installed properly

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, installation, mingw

By taking reference from a medium.com website, I built OpenCV library of version 4.6.0 for MingW.
I even added the required `bin` folders into the Environment Variables assuming that the program would detect the used libraries but unfortunately it didn't.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

throws an error that states:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Some extra details:

- Installed G++ (12.2.0) from winlibs.com (ucrt-posix-seh build) and this works as intended
- Built with CMake while keeping Mingw for configuration.
- `C:\Program Files\OpenCV\install\x64\mingw\bin` and `C:\Program Files\OpenCV\bin` have been added to the environment variables
- I did try adding `lib` folder to windows path variables, that didn't help either
- This is the 4th build that I'm trying

It is basic common sense that the directories should be added to the environment variables which I've done. I've doubled checked the folder by manually visiting it and all the required `.hpp` and `.dll` files do exist.

Folder structure:

- `C:\Program Files\mingw64`, this is where the G++ has been isntalled
- `C:\Program Files\OpenCV\bin`, below didn't detect, so I even added this into environment variables. Also, both have same/similar files with same names. (I compared  them.)
- `C:\Program Files\OpenCV\install\x64\mingw\bin`, this bin file is what I'm supposed to add.
- `C:\Program Files\OpenCV\install\include\opencv2`, `hpp` files exist here..

OS:
Windows 10 [22H2]

Comment: It's true that, very often, trying to cram Linux/Unix originated software, like gcc, into a foreign operating system that wasn't designed to run Linux/Unix-originated code, turns out to be a major, major time sink. Even experienced developers will struggle with this, not to mention those who are new to C++. Most of the time it takes much less time to simply install Linux from scratch, and get a fully working, fully configured, modern C++ compiler. It took me just an hour and a half, last time. Now, I'd just buy a Lenovo laptop with preloaded Linux. How much time did you already spend on this?

Comment: 3 hours went in drain today. 4 hours yesterday. Have worked a bit with opencv-python but this is the first time me using opencv in c++

Comment: Try to think logically. Just because there are header files installed somewhere on your computer doesn't mean that a C++ compiler knows where they are. The compiler is not going to scan the entire hard drive, looking for every header file. The compiler has a predefined list of directories where header files are installed. The chances are that your C++ compiler knows about `C:\Program Files\OpenCV\install\include` are slim to none. Wherever you have your C++ installed, that's where its standard library header files are, and where it looks. For all other directories the `-I` option must be used.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I've to use `-I` command during compilation. I may sound a bit dumb, what if I move/copy the opencv libs to the place where the standard c++ libraries are kept? (I believe I've to try to get to know..) However, one thing that still bothers me is that, even after adding the bin folder to windows path dir, how does it go undetected?

Comment: Well, if this was Linux something like that requires a single symbolic link. There might be an equivalent to symlinks on Windows, dunno. I would not manually screw around with installations of packaged software. I do not make structural changes, like that, myself, I always strictly install my distribution's packages, as is. If necessary I make my own packages and install them. Manually screwing around with installed files eventually ends in tears.

Comment: if you're only concerned about getting stuff done, with OpenCV, perhaps use it from Python. most "performance" worries are immaterial because people simply don't know how to tickle performance out of Python, which is fairly easy, if you know how (numba, cython, OpenCV with OpenCL or CUDA, ...)

Comment: I wanted play around and learn OpenCV with C++. I had no idea that I would get in the installation itself...

Comment: My advice is to switch to use [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) to provide MinGW and use the builtin package manager pacman to install [opencv](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-opencv?repo=mingw64) for you. Everything that you install using pacman will be in a folder that the MinGW compiler from msys2 already looks. You will still have to use the `-l` option to link but it saves you the step of a more complicated install process and setting include and linker paths and any worry about incompatible binaries.

Comment: To install x64 OpenCV open the mingw64 terminal and type `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-opencv` which is listed in the install instructions page I linked in the previous comment.